# mIRC scripting like string token manipulation in Lua

Tags: strings, lua

I'm trying to reproduce in Lua the  mIRC scripting manipulating tokens function:

```
local function tokenize(C, text)
    local char = string.format("%c", C)
    local t = {}
    for w in string.gmatch(tostring(text), "[^"..char.."]+") do
    w = tonumber(w) or tostring(w)
    table.insert(t,w)
    end
    return t
end

local function gettok(strng, position, separator, range)
  local char = string.format("%c", separator)
  local tokens = tokenize(separator, strng)
  local result, n, r, start, stop
  if (position ~= 0) then
    if (position > 0) then n = position else n = #tokens + position + 1 end
    if (range) and (position ~= range) then
      if (range > 0) then r = range

      elseif (range == 0) or ((n + range) > #tokens) then r = #tokens
      else r = n + (range + 1)
      end
      if (n == r) then
        result = tokens[i]
      else
        start = (r >= n) and n or r
        stop = (r <= n) and n or r
        for i = start, stop do
          result = (not result) and tokens[i] or tostring(result..char..tokens[i])
        end
      end
    else
      for i = 1, #tokens do
        if (i == n) then result = tokens[i] end
      end
    end
  else result = strng
  end
  return result
end
```

And this is the way it should work:

```
gettok(strng, position, separator, range)
```

Where

- `strng` = string to manipulate
- `position` = position of the token inside the string. If lesser than 0, it will be considered the position from the last token to the first. If equal to 0, returns the whole string.
- `separator` = ASCII code of the token separator
- `range` = optional: if specified, returns the token from position to range. If equal to 0, return all tokens from position to the end of the string.

---

```
local text = "apple.banana.cherry.grape.orange"
```

- > apple

  ```
  gettok(text,1,46)
  ```
- > grape

  ```
  gettok(text,-2,46)
  ```
- > banana.cherry.grape

  ```
  gettok(text,2,46,4)
  ```
- > cherry.grape.orange

  ```
  gettok(text,-1,46,-3)
  ```

Could you give me some advice on improving the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need to use `tostring` inside [`string.match`](https://devdocs.io/lua/index#pdf-table.concat) or other methods provided by [`string`](https://devdocs.io/lua/index#pdf-string) meta-table.
2. I'd suggest allowing users to pass the character as well as ASCII-code for the `separator`. This is of course, you own choice and nothing needs to be done in the code to enforce this.
3. The following loop:

   ```
   for i = 1, #tokens do
       if (i == n) then result = tokens[i] end
   end
   ```

   is entirely useless and can be replaced with `result = tokens[n]`.
4. I do not understand your reasons behind the following conversion:

   ```
   w = tonumber(w) or tostring(w)
   ```

   `w` will be type `string` by default.
5. You can use [`table.concat`](https://devdocs.io/lua/index#pdf-string) effectively; instead of [creating string buffers](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.6.html).
6. Instead of writing long winded `if-else` blocks, put the smaller blocks forward and return results as soon as you arrive at one.
7. In lua, you do not necessarily need to put the `if`-conditions inside parentheses.
8. What does a negative `range` imply? I tested your function with `gettok(text, -3, 46, -2)` expecting `cherry.grape` as output, instead; I received `banana.cherry`.
9. For your `start` and `stop` values, use `math.max` and `math.min`.

The rewritten code follows. Please note that I've used *my own convention* of variable naming.

```
local function Tokenize( sChar, sInput )
    local tReturn = {}
    for sWord in string.gmatch( sInput, "[^"..sChar.."]+" ) do
        table.insert( tReturn, tonumber(sWord) or sWord )
    end
    return tReturn
end

local function GetTok( sInput, iPosition, Separator, iRange )
    local Separator = string.format( '%c', Separator )
    local tTokens = Tokenize( Separator, sInput )
    if iPosition == 0 then
        return sInput
    end
    local iStart, iStop = ( iPosition > 0 ) and iPosition or ( #tTokens + iPosition + 1 )
    if not iRange or iPosition == iRange then
        return tTokens[ iStart ]
    end
    if iRange > 0 then
        iStop = iRange
    elseif iRange == 0 or ( iStart + iRange ) > #tTokens then
        iStop = #tTokens
    else
        iStop = iStart + iRange + 1
    end
    if iStart == iStop then
        return tTokens[ iStart ]
    end
    if iStart > iStop then
        iStart, iStop = iStop, iStart
    end
    return table.concat( tTokens, Separator, iStart, iStop )
end
```